# What is the difference between blame and accuse?

Tags: difference, word-difference

Is there any difference in meaning between *blame* and *accuse* or are they interchangeable? I looked both of them up in the dictionaries and couldn't figure out if there's any difference between them.
**Dictionary Definitions**
*Accuse* → If you accuse someone of doing something wrong or dishonest, you say or tell them that you believe that they did it.
*Blame* → If you blame a person or thing for something bad, you believe or say that they are responsible for it or that they caused it.

Comment: What did you find confusing about the definitions when you looked them up in the dictionary? They are similar and it would help us write better answers if you explained your current understanding.

Comment: When I looked them up in the dictionaries, I found them very much similar in meaning. I couldn't figure out what the difference between both of them was.

Comment: They are related and similar, but not identical.  Can you edit your question to include the definitions that you are having trouble differentiating?  Or maybe present a situation where you aren't sure which should be used?

Comment: @Adam I've included the definitions.

Comment: I think the key difference is _that you believe that they did it_ and _you believe or say that they are responsible for it_.

Comment: Another difference is that blame can be apportioned (as if it was a quantity), e.g. "I partially blame the government for allowing this to happen" whereas an accusation is either made or not made - you can't "partially accuse" someone.

Answer (score 9):

Formally, we use **accuse** with an **act**—we assert that somebody **did** something reprehensible:

> Mary accuses John of failing to lock the door.

But we use **blame** with the **outcome**—we assert somebody's responsibility for the undesirable result:

> Mary blames John for the robbery.  *OR*
>   Mary blames the robbery on John.

Informally, however, these distinctions often blur. For instance, if the robbery has already been mentioned, *blame* may very easily take a *for* clause which explains *why* the target is blamed:

> Mary's house has been robbed. Mary blames John, for failing [*=because he failed*] to lock the door.

And *accuse* may take a complement which expresses a state rather than an act:

> Mary accuses John of being responsible for the robbery.

Comment: A key part of the difference to me is that _accuse_ is always an external act.  Blame may not be. Someone can blame their neighbor for killing their dog but never say a word to anyone about it - keep it all inside their own head.   Blame can also be used to mean "make public your assessment of guilt" - it works either way, but _accuse_ is always a public airing.

Answer (score -1):

Blame is thinking that someone did something wrong.
Accuse is witnessing that someone did something wrong and stating that.

Comment: Wrong in all respects.

Answer (score -2):

When a PERSON(n) is added to the QUESTION it can easily become an ACCUSATION or in a court of law it can also be called "Leading".

Scenario: I'm really busy today so I can't take Grandma to the Store.
Question: Can you please try and take grandma to the store?
Leading: Do you not love your Grandma enough to take her to the Store?

There are also subtle nuances of the english language where a person can take offense and feel like they are being accused just in the order their name is inserted into the question like so:

Scenario: Johns Wallet is missing.
Question:  What happened to my wallet?
Accusation: What happened to my wallet John?

There are also generalized accusations where a person may "FEEL" accused.

Scenario:  Marry comes home and feels really hot.
Question:  I'm hot, can you turn ON the A/C?
Accusation:  I'm hot, did you turn OFF the A/C?