# Why do we use 'of' with accuse while we use 'for' with blame?

Tags: meaning, prepositions, word-meaning

I've gone through [this post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/48177/3448) and I understand the difference between *accuse* and *blame*. What I don't understand is that why don't we use "for" with accuse. E.g we say,

> He's been accused of murder.

And in case of *blame*, we say,

> He has been blamed for the* murder.

Why don't we say "*He's been accused **for** the murder*"? I guess that we use *for* only to mention the reason and in case of *accuse*, *He* is not responsible for murder but is actually the murderer. Please explain which grammar rule is acting here and also please explain the meaning or sense of the incorrect version(accused for), i.e. how do native English speakers take it.

* I'm not sure that *the* should be there or not.

Comment: See [**blame for**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/blame+for) and [**accuse of**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/accuse+of).

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between blame and accuse?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/48177/what-is-the-difference-between-blame-and-accuse)

Comment: @user3169 The answer to that question is a little helpful, but it seems to me that this is really asking for the difference between 'for' and 'of', rather than between 'accuse' and 'blame'. He's blamed *for* *the* murder, meaning that he's the *cause* of that particular murder. He's accused *of* murder, because being accused is an attribute of the person. We use *of* when expressing attributes or properties. The distinction is not super clear-cut, and which preposition to use if often one of those things that a native speaker knows without knowing exactly why.

Comment: Related: [Difference between the use of “for” and “of”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7425/difference-between-the-use-of-for-and-of)

Comment: Fixed form (phrasal verbs): Suspected **of** murder...a suspect **in the** murder....blamed **for the** murder...arrested **for** murder. ..arrested **on suspicion of** murder.  Charged **with** murder. Accused **of** murder. Indicted **for** murder. Tried **for** murder.  Convicted (or acquitted) **of** murder.

Answer (score 1):

The expressions are simply fixed. Many verbs combine with a preposition in a fixed expression.

As for the difference between the two verbs, you can find that in [What is the difference between blame and accuse?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/48177/what-is-the-difference-between-blame-and-accuse).

Comment: I don't think they are simply fixed. AFAIK _for_ is used for telling reason, time  etc and similarly _of_ is used in certain relationship with the words around it. What is the meaning of "of" and "for" in these sentences? And if they are sim[ply fixed then do we cram the words with which _for_ has to be used instead of _of_?

Comment: The verbs can often take different prepositions, but with different meanings. At my university we've had to cram a list of verbs with fixed prepositions. 'to accuse' was one of them. But there are verbs that have different prepositions or even none. For example: 'approve'. Without a preposition it does not mean the same thing as 'approve of'. So with fixed I do not mean that the verb ALWAYS takes that preposition, but to express that specific meaning it does.

Comment: Is it also true in other languages? In my language I have not crammed any combination of 'word+preposition'. Every preposition has a fixed rule and meaning.

Comment: These verbs are called 'phrasal verbs'. And yes, they exist in other languages as well :)

Comment: I'm not sure what either of you mean by *cram* — do you mean *study*? Or *pair*?

Comment: @choster I mean pair. I never remember any pair of type word+preposition in my language. E.g. _from_ is similar to the preposition _se_ in my language which is used after(in English before) a word that tells the initial point/starting point of something, this rule is always fixed in my language whatever pair of _se+word_ I make.

Comment: @SandervanHommelen is _accused + of_ a phrasal construction or does it obey usual meaning of _of_?

Comment: I thought it was, but after researching a bit more I am not so sure anymore :P

Comment: @SandervanHommelen I've started to read the [wikipedea](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrasal_verb) article. It seems like phrasal verbs are idiom like structures. I've another question. In sentence _I know of two things_, is _of=about_?

Comment: Yes, I now think that it is not a phrasal verb. The 'of' is simply a fixed  preposition with the verb.

Comment: @choster The way Sander used 'cram', it meant study a lot in a short period of time. This is often used when you are preparing for a test at the last minute, or when you need to memorize a lot of set information.

Comment: I indeed meant study, but overlooked your question. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

The verb construction to accuse someone of a crime is a construction with historical roots. Already in Latin  accusare (to accuse) was used with accusative (person) and genitive (crime).

The genitive may be made plausible with two sententences: He was accused. Why? It is the accusation of murder.